# Was the "Tour" removed?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed

In researching to respond to a question, I tried to find the site tour and couldn't find it.  Is it gone?  I hope not -- it was a good resource, even for experienced users.

Update: Found it here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour -- but it really belongs in the drop down help list.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393737/the-tour-link-has-disappeared-from-the-help-menu-in-the-top-bar

Comment: Scott - Hi, FYI it has now been fixed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The tour is now back in the top bar drop-down menu.**

See the earlier version of my answer below, where SE said this was an unintentional change which they were fixing. It has now been fixed (at least on our site).

---

---

As *[dim](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/107479/dim)* kindly [commented](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9924/was-the-tour-removed#comment21224_9924), this has been recognised as a regression on Meta.SE:

["The tour link has disappeared from the help menu in the top bar"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393737/the-tour-link-has-disappeared-from-the-help-menu-in-the-top-bar)

I'll make that information more visible by posting it as this answer.

The SE staff member (actually VP) *[Philippe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/936316/philippe)* said on that page:

> This was an unintentional regression. We're working on getting a fix pushed out right now. Will update when completed.

Here's a screenshot of [that Meta.SE page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393737/the-tour-link-has-disappeared-from-the-help-menu-in-the-top-bar) currently (click for the full size version):

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

You're right, it's not where it used to be (Help center and other resources):

[image]

You can (still) find it in the footer:

[image]